# Определение собственного датасета из синтетики в pytorch

Tags: машинное-обучение, pytorch, графики, датасет

Имеется набор изображений jpeg с синтезированными графиками, разбитых на 3 класса по 300 штук в каждом + 90 графиков для тестовой выборки.

Планируется создать нейросеть, определяющая класс графика по изображению на входе.
Никак не могу разобраться, как создать в Pytorch собственный датасет с изображениями, т.к.все туториалы в интернете про то, как использовать готовые сеты из интернета.

Прошу привести пример реализации датасета из Jpeg или любую ссылку на материал по этой теме.

Спасибо.

Прикладываю текущую иерархию папок с изображениями + пример изображения каждого класса

[image: Иерархия изображений]

[image: Класс Downs]

[image: Класс Peaks]

[image: Класс Rises]

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйтесь [torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder](https://pytorch.org/vision/0.8/datasets.html#imagefolder).

[Пример](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/105102/torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder):

```
transform_dict = {
        'src': transforms.Compose(
        [transforms.RandomResizedCrop(224),
         transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
         transforms.ToTensor(),
         transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406],
                              std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225]),
         ]),
        'tar': transforms.Compose(
        [transforms.Resize(224),
         transforms.ToTensor(),
         transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406],
                              std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225]),
         ])
}
data = datasets.ImageFolder(root=root_path + dir, transform=transform_dict[phase])
data_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(data, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True, 
                                          drop_last=False, num_workers=4)
```